# reactjs sending props to children error before server response loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to set the initial state as blank, then load up data for the components an Ajax Request. However, before the ajax request runs, I'm hit with the error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'max_level' of undefined`. I even attempted to set the initial state, but without specifically referencing the `max_level` attribute, I receive an error. I do not want set copy the entire schema to the initial state because my data structure if quite complex and can change.

```
class AvailableUpgradeContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      available_upgrades: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadAvailableUpgradesFromServer();
  }
  loadAvailableUpgradesFromServer() {
    $.ajax({ ... })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AvailableUpgradeTable available_upgrades={this.state.available_upgrades} />
    )
  }
}

class AvailableUpgradeTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.available_upgrades.map((building) =>
          <AvailableUpgradeTableRow max_level={building.max_level} />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you double check if the `$.ajax` is not being called before the error hits?

Comment: The success of the $.ajax request happens after error hits.

Comment: try encapsulating the statement below your map function with curlys?

Comment: You're calling `.map()` on `this.props.available_upgrades`, but everything else references `this.state.available_upgrades`. If that's intentional, can you post a sample of where this component is actually used?

Comment: @rossipedia, it's how react component works. `this.state.available_upgrades` is passed on to the `props` of  Component `AvailableUpgradeTable`

Comment: yeah, now that I look at it, it looks to be some syntax issue. you've got a missing closing `)`

Comment: Yes, I know. I missed that there were two components there in your sample. That error means that there's an element in the array, but it's undefined. I'm not entirely certain how that could be, but I am unable to repro: http://jsbin.com/daqeve/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Also your `AvailableUpgradeTable` component needs to have a single child element (as all React components do). Currently you're returning the result of a `map()` call, which won't work. Wrap it in a `<div>` or something (as in my example on jsbin)

Comment: Thanks for noticing the syntax errors. Those were due to simplifying my code and being hung over. I've now enclosed the react component in a single child and added the missing closing `)`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried putting your code into jsFiddle and it had some syntax errors. Those parentheses are a pain to look at so I kind of refractored to a point there were no longer syntax errors.

Here;s the resulting code

```
class AvailableUpgradeTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div> 
        { mapUpgrades(this.props.available_upgrades) } 
      </div>
    )
  }
  mapUpgrades(upgrades){
    upgrades.map(building => {      
        return (
            <AvailableUpgradeTableRow max_level={building.max_level} />
        )
    });
  }
}
```